# How Can I Split some Value from this result

Tags: python

```
                time     open     high      low    close  tick_volume  spread  real_volume
 0 2020-01-08 12:00:00  1.11382  1.11385  1.11110  1.11199         9354       1            0
 1 2020-01-08 16:00:00  1.11199  1.11308  1.11086  1.11179        10641       1            0
 2 2020-01-08 20:00:00  1.11178  1.11178  1.11016  1.11053         4806       1            0
 3 2020-01-09 00:00:00  1.11053  1.11193  1.11033  1.11173         3480       1            0
 4 2020-01-09 04:00:00  1.11173  1.11189  1.11126  1.11182         2236       1            0
 5 2020-01-09 08:00:00  1.11181  1.11203  1.10983  1.10993         7984       1            0
```

I have this chart and I'm trying to get the values like Open, High, Low and close.

```
firstvalue = line.split()[4]
```

i'm getting the error

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'split'
```

please help me how this work.

Comment: share some code please, what is ```line```?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are applying the method 'split'(for strings) on a Pandas DataFrame, but your column is already split. So you should try to do:

```
print(line['Open'])
```

In the variable that in this example you call 'line' you have already all the dataset. Maybe because you are reading the file with:

```
import pandas as pd
line = pd.read_csv('filename.csv') # in this case line contains all the file
print(line['column_name']) # returns the content of an entire column
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `DataFrame.loc` splitting methods to achieve what your want.

Supposing you have a DataFrame called `df`:

```
# You'll get all lines from 'time' column.
df.loc[:,'time'] 

# Filter index lines from 3 to 5 (both inclusive) and columns from 'time' to 'close'
df.loc[3:5,'time':'close']

# Select the value from 'low' corresponding to index 5
df.loc[5,'low']

# Select the values from columns 'time' and 'low' of corresponding indexes 0, 4 and 5
df.loc[ (0, 4, 5), ('time', 'low') ]
```

If you want to improve your skills, just check the `pandsa.DataFrame.loc`documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html).

There are a lot of more examples about how to split your DataFrame.

---

Specific about your error: you are trying to use a string method in a DataFrame object.

That's why you are receiving this error message.

Try to look for DataFrame methods and attributes in [this link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)

Hope this was helpful.